# RdKit Coordinates for atoms in a molecule

Tags: python, chemistry, rdkit

Hey everyone I need some help formatting coordinates for atoms in a molecule and I'm coding with Python. What I am needing is along the lines of:

```py
(atom) x y z coordinates
```

For every atom in the molecule. So far my code is:

```py
for molecule in mol_list:
    molecule = Chem.AddHs(molecule)
    print(molecule.GetNumAtoms())
    AllChem.EmbedMolecule(molecule)
    AllChem.UFFOptimizeMolecule(molecule)
    molecule.GetConformer()

    print()

    for atom in molecule.GetAtoms():
        # positions = molecule.GetConformer().GetAtomPosition(0)
        positions = molecule.GetConformer().GetPositions()
        print(atom.GetSymbol(), positions)
    
        print()
```

But this gives me the output of:

```py
(Atom) x y z coordinates for every atom
```

This repeats so that every atom in the molecule has the entire molecule's x, y, and z coordinates. `mol_list` in the `for` loop is a list of strings that I converted to the object: `rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol`. I've tried the `geometry.xyz` function in `Chemml`, but ran into issues with the Molecule object. Also, I've tried using the `RdKit` function `getAtomPos()` with no luck. Any help with this would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the atom number to get its coordinates. The following code snippet should do what you're looking for

```py
for molecule in mol_list:
    molecule = Chem.AddHs(molecule)
    print(molecule.GetNumAtoms())
    AllChem.EmbedMolecule(molecule)
    AllChem.UFFOptimizeMolecule(molecule)
    molecule.GetConformer()
    print()

    for i, atom in enumerate(molecule.GetAtoms()):
        positions = molecule.GetConformer().GetAtomPosition(i)
        print(atom.GetSymbol(), positions.x, positions.y, positions.z)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this did exactly what I needed